# Best practice for data migration

Tags: sql, migration, data-migration

Currently We have developed a system for a manual work they have been doing using many excel files.

Is there a best practice for data migration? because I wanted to use backend language like .net to do the validation and insert into tables rather than using SQL to do migration.

Total record in excel is around 12K rows but for many tables so its not needed consider a lot about performance and it is only one time.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a few calculated columns in Excel that would generate SQL Insert / Update scripts. Something like `="INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('"&A1&"');"`

Then just copy calculated column and run it through SQL client. I used to have a macros to run it directly from Excel through OLEDB that would highlight failed expressions and store SQL Exceptions next to them.

That way the data can be easily tidied, corrected and SQL re-run as needed.